# Drag and drop - how to freeze the hit object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I've got 2 objects - a sphere and a cube. When I drag the sphere and hit the cube with it, the cube is flying away. How can I make the hit objects stay in the same position even if they are hit with the another (dragged) object? When I checked the Constraints-Freeze Position in Rigidbody, the sphere just went through the cube.

Here is the code I use to drag and drop (both objects have that script attached + rigidbody):

```
     private bool dragging = false;
 private float distance;

 void OnMouseDown()
 {
     distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Camera.main.transform.position);
     dragging = true;
 }

 void OnMouseUp()
 {
     dragging = false;
 }

 void Update()
 {
     if (dragging)
     {
         Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
         Vector3 rayPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
         transform.position = rayPoint;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is Rigidbody attached to this Object you're dragging?

Comment: As said, both objects have Rigidbody attached

Answer (score 0):

Enable kinematic checkbox on the rigidbody of the gameobject you want to be immobile.

Comment: Tried this one too, still goes through

Comment: Provide some screen please because it's quite impossible

Comment: https://imgur.com/YYAz0Zj
If Is Kinematic is disabled, the cube gets pushed by the sphere, if it's enabled it goes through, but if I drop it like inside the cube, it jumps out from the cube

Comment: Did you test onCollisionEnter methods to debug?

Comment: I tried with `   void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        GameObject otherObj = collision.gameObject;
        Debug.Log("Collided with: " + otherObj);
    }` I'm getting "Collided with: Cube (UnityEngine.GameObject)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)"